# Как заблокировать установку сертификатов в Доверенные издатели?

Tags: windows, windowsinstaller

Некоторые инсталляторы пытаются установить свои сертификаты в хранилище "Доверенные издатели" локальной машины.

Можно ли запретить эту установку, даже под правами администратора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть ещё один ответ - самый очевидный. Нужно заблокировать изменение ветви реестра ответственной за хранение сертификатов:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\TrustedPublisher\Certificates

В ней нужно задать доступ на чтение, в том числе и "СОЗДАТЕЛЮ-ВЛАДЕЛЬЦУ", к которой, кстати, относится группа "Администраторов" компьютера.
После этого исчезает возможность изменять хранилище сертификатов TrustedPublisher локального компьютера.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял, нужно "заморозить" текущее хранилище сертификатов TrustedPublisher.
Учитывая, что аудит таких событий, скорее всего, не ведется, я предложил бы следующее. Надо сверять "эталонный" список после событий, которые указывают на возможность установки.

1. Нужно создать эталонный список сертификатов, да хотя бы и просто
   обычным списком. Пойдет даже консоль:

   certutil -store TrustedPublisher
2. Установить триггеры на события установки, можно привязать даже на события журнала "Установка".
3. В выполняемой команде триггеров надо выгружать список и сверять его
   с эталонным. При несовпадении генерировать событие безопасности
   (оповещать админов и т.д.). А затем восстанавливать список, хотя бы
   и через те же команды certutil(dellstore,addstore).

P.S. Если комп находится в инфраструктуре AD и на нём предполагается типовая конфигурация. То я бы рассмотрел вариант с распространением сертификатов через функционал GPO.